# Unexpected token 'endpackage'

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I`m trying to use this pkg:

```
package x_mater_pkg;

`timescale 1 ns/1 ps
import uvm_pkg::*;
`include "uvm_macros.svh"

localparam DATA_W = 128;
localparam x_PORTS = 4;
localparam ADDR_WIDTH = 2;

`include "x_driver.sv"
`include "x_env.sv"
`include "x_master_agent.sv"
`include "xsequence.sv"
`include "x.sv"
`include "x_sequencer.sv"
`include "x_tx_seq_item.sv"
`include "x_top.sv"

 endpackage : x_master_pkg
```

in my top module :

```
 module top_x;

 import x_master_pkg::*;
 ...
 endmodule
```

keep getting an error, does someone have an idea why? In other situations an instance of my slave interface does not recognized.

Comment: looks like you have an issue inside x_top.sv file

Comment: modules are not allowed to be a part of a package, so you cannot include it.

Answer (score 1):

SV packages cannot include other design elements. A `module` is a design element and cannot be inside of the package. So, your `include` should not be there.

The usual way to handle packages is

1. include parameters, classes, functions, ... other non-design elements inside the package.
2. import the package in the module which uses its members.
3. compile the model so, that the file containing package is compiled before its use.

x_mater_pkg.sv

```
package x_mater_pkg;
localparam DATA_W = 128;
localparam x_PORTS = 4;
localparam ADDR_WIDTH = 2;
...
endpackage
```

x_top.sv

```
`include "uvm_macros.svh"
 module top_x;
   import uvm_pkg::*
   import x_master_pkg::*;
   ...
 endmodue
```

then

```
compile uvm_pkg.sv x_mater_pkg.sv x_top.sv
```

Comment: i assumed that x_top.sv is the container for the top_x module. Could be wrong.

Comment: Let the OP comment, if i am wrong, i will delete the answer. But you are correct in one thing, there would probably be an error on the keyword 'module' in such a case.

Comment: Modules cannot be declared inside a package. Refer to [IEEE1800-2017](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2017.html) section 26 (Packages). "SystemVerilog packages provide an additional mechanism for sharing parameters, data, type, task, function, sequence, property, and checker declarations among multiple SystemVerilog modules, interfaces, programs, and checkers."

Comment: top_x and x_top are different, but still I think the mistake was to include another modules  that are  inside other files such as `include "x_driver.sv", no?

Comment: Yes, this was definitely the problem